# Autodesk - Unable to upload images to Photo scene

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am having issues with sending files to the endpoint: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file

Once I receive the Auth token, I successfully create a Photo Scene with: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene.
Then I also check, if the Photo scene is indeed created by calling the: [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/${photosceneid}/properties](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/$%7Bphotosceneid%7D/properties).

If that goes through, I send the image files, which I first upload to a storage server
(because sending the files directly didnt work) and then I run:

```
let image_urls = await temporary_image_upload(files, photosceneid)
const form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("photosceneid", photosceneid)
form_data.append("type", "image")
image_urls.forEach(url => form_data.append("file", url))

// I also tried:
// image_urls.forEach((url, index) => form_data.append(`file[${index}]`, url))

// Upload photos
const { data } = await axios.post(
  "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file",
  form_data,
  { headers }
)
//
//
// I also tried adding it as query params:

image_urls = image_urls.map((url, index) => `file[${index}]=${url}`).join("&")

// Upload photos
const { data } = await axios.post(
  "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file",
  `photosceneid=${photosceneid}&type=image&${image_urls}`,
  { headers }
)
```

But nothing seems to work and I get response:

```
{
  Usage: '0.47925591468811',
  Resource: '/file',
  Error: {
    code: '19',
    msg: "Specified Photoscene ID doesn't exist in the database"
  }
}
```

So I am not sure what might be wrong, since I can clearly verify that the Photo Scene has been created.

Could you please provide some support, been struggling with this for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you can clearly confirm the `photosceneid` exists, I would suspect that your axios request is not as expected, maybe add details about your header. Here is a sample:

```
Axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        data: querystring.stringify({
            photosceneid: photosceneId,
            type: 'image',
            'file[0]': 'https://path/to/file.JPG'
        })
    })
```